# Adding summernote Class to simple_form form causes it to break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, summernote

I added simple_form gem and its corresponding instructions, and i see the editor and all, but when I add the class to my form...it doesn't seem to be working. However, when I delete the class: 'summernote', the form functions correctly.

Here's what i have in my _form.html.erb. Note that the form works 100% fine as long as i don't assign it a class of summernote.

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@project, @task]) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'summernote' } %>
  </div>

  <h3>Extra Tasks?</h3>

  <div id="tasks">
    <%= f.fields_for :extratasks do |extratask| %>
      <%= render 'extratask_fields', f: extratask %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add extratask', f, :extratasks %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I've also tried doing `<%= f.input :description, as: :summernote%>` , but that only causes the original input field to overlap the summernote field.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this I think work:
 f.input :description, html: { class: 'summernote' }

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It causes the editor to go away actually.